# WordPress linking to subpages

Tags: wordpress

I have made a subpage(accreditations.php) for my about_us.php page. I have done this by creating the page in wordpress and making the about us page the parent. I then made a php file for the accreditations page and applied a template name like you normally would so that I can edit it in my text editor.

To get the link to work I did this

```
<a href="accreditations" class="absolute_img_links">Accreditations</a>
```

which linked to the accreditations page through the about us page like this

website.co.uk/about-us/accreditations/

Now I'm wondering how this has worked? and if it is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I have just realised that this method is wrong as when I click the link again it adds it to the url again for example, website.co.uk/about-us/accreditations/accreditations

Answer (score 0):

You must **mention the full URL** for `href`.

```
<a href="http://website.co.uk/accreditations" class="absolute_img_links">Accreditations</a>
```

Or

With WordPress you can use the `get_template_directory_uri()` function to get path to your template directory. You might not need this for this case. But just additional information I wanted to add.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was echoing the pages id in the href

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link(130); ?>">Accreditations</a>
```